# Overlays make content of columns jump in beamer

Tags: beamer, columns, overlays

I have a part of my beamer frame in a `\columns` environment. When an `\item` appears in the left column, the tree diagram in the right column jumps up and down. I'd like to keep the diagram in the same place across slides.

I have the whole body of the frame in an `\overlayarea` but this doesn't seem to help.

Here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}    

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} \footnotesize
\frametitle{A Heading for my Frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item This is an item.
\end{itemize}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.9\textheight}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Some more Items
    %           \onslide*<2-7>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> This is an item
        \item<5-> This is an item
    \end{itemize}%}

    \item<8-> More Items
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
        \onslide+<9->{
            %               \scalebox{.8}{ 
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[draw](tree){ 
                \begin{forest}
                [ VP
                [ VP
                [ Node ]
                [ Node]]
                [ Node ]]
                \end{forest}};

            \onslide+<12->{
                \draw[red, thick] (tree.south east) to (tree.north west);
                \draw[red, thick] (tree.south west) to (tree.north east);}

            \end{tikzpicture}}%}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item<10-> This is a relatively long question that stretches two lines ?
            \onslide*<11-12>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item *Here the whole thing jumps
                        \item *Here the whole thing jumps
                        \item *Here the whole thing jumps
                    \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}}
            \item<13-> Everything jumps back.
            \item<14-> Concluding remarks.
        \end{itemize}

    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{overlayarea}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave an empty line after `This is a relatively long question that stretches two lines ?`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}    

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} \footnotesize
\frametitle{A Heading for my Frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item This is an item.
\end{itemize}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.9\textheight}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Some more Items
    %           \onslide*<2-7>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> This is an item
        \item<5-> This is an item
    \end{itemize}%}

    \item<8-> More Items
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
        \onslide+<9->{
            %               \scalebox{.8}{ 
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[draw](tree){ 
                \begin{forest}
                [ VP
                [ VP
                [ Node ]
                [ Node]]
                [ Node ]]
                \end{forest}};

            \onslide+<12->{
                \draw[red, thick] (tree.south east) to (tree.north west);
                \draw[red, thick] (tree.south west) to (tree.north east);}

            \end{tikzpicture}}%}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item<10-> This is a relatively long question that stretches two lines ?

            \onslide*<11-12>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item *Here the whole thing jumps
                        \item *Here the whole thing jumps
                        \item *Here the whole thing jumps
                    \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}}
            \item<13-> Everything jumps back.
            \item<14-> Concluding remarks.
        \end{itemize}

    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{overlayarea}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. You also added the `[T]`arguement to the `columns` environment, which also helps. (btw I don't know why I chose to have the first column at `.15\textwidth` , but it seems to work fine.)